# TRIGGER with INSERT AND UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I need help on creating a trigger on my `table1` that will insert specific columns into `table2` from `table1`. How can I do that? I am using Oracle 11G XE .

Here is my code:

```
create or replace trigger AllowanceTrigger
after insert on ex_bulacan
for each row
begin
    insert into allowance (PLANT_ORIGIN,SO_NO, SO_STATUS,SO_REMARKS,DRIVER_NAME)
    values (:new.plant_origin, :new.sales_order_no, :new.status,:new.remarks, :new.driver_name);
end; ​
```

What if they update the data in `ex_bulacan`? Will automatically change my `allowance` table as well?

Comment: It won't change when they update because your trigger is only `after insert`

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you want the trigger to fire when there are updates to `ex_bulacan`, you would need the trigger to be defined both `after insert` and `after update`.  If you want to update the `allowance` table, you'd want something like

```
create or replace trigger AllowanceTrigger
after insert or update on ex_bulacan
for each row
begin
  if( inserting )
  then
    insert into allowance (PLANT_ORIGIN,
                           SO_NO, 
                           SO_STATUS,
                           SO_REMARKS,
                           DRIVER_NAME)
    values (:new.plant_origin, 
            :new.sales_order_no, 
            :new.status,
            :new.remarks, 
            :new.driver_name);
  end if;

  if( updating )
  then
    update allowance
       set plant_origin = :new.plant_origin,
           so_status = :new.status,
           so_remarks = :new.remarks,
           driver_name = :new.driver_name
     where so_no = :new.sales_order_no;
  end if;
end; ​
```

That said, having two tables with the same set of data strongly implies that you've got a problem with improper normalization.  It would generally be much better to fix the data model rather than trying to keep the data in two tables in sync via triggers.

Comment: Okay i'm gonna try your code.. what i want if the SO_NO in ex_bulacan is already in allowance table it will automaticaly update the data in allowance table.Thanks!!

Comment: i got this error master please help about this"Compilation failed, line 23 (12:26:16) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers."
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Comment: @MichaelPilapil - Did you see the edit I made to fix a missing `END IF`?  If you want to update the `allowance` table based on the `so_no`, the `WHERE` clause in the second `UPDATE` would need to reference `so_no`.  I'm guessing that would mean that you'd want to `UPDATE` the `plant_origin` column as well.

Comment: Actually Sir @JustinCave only the so_no thai will not change thats my unique key for both tables how can i do that? please help me sir..

Comment: @MichaelPilapil - Updated my answer to use `so_no` as the key rather than `plant_origin`.

Comment: please give me the exact query for that? do i have to give parameter to IF?like if so_no = :new.sales_order_no

Comment: @MichaelPilapil - I told you, I updated my answer.  The current answer should, if I understand, be the exact statement you're looking for.

Comment: i got this error when i compile your code "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null" what will i do for this? Pardon sir please help me..

Comment: @MichaelPilapil you should mark the answer as accepted. You'll have benefits from that. And others, and the site will be better with accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need a trigger defined like this:

create or replace trigger AllowanceTrigger after insert or update.....

or you could create two triggers - one for insert, and one for update

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments from @e-bacho 2.0 nothing will happen during update.
You must specify a trigger also for the `after update` event. or implment your actual trigger to handle also the update

Comment: the answer from Justin Cave should do what you need